# What are the songs played in Stargate: Atlantis' *Vegas* episode?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis, music-identification

One of the reasons *Vegas* (S5:E19) that makes it unique, as well as one of my favorite episodes, is the liberal use of "commercial off the shelf" music performed by famous artists. I can pick out some of them:

- When the Wraith is putting on his makeup - *The Beautiful People* (Marilyn Manson)

  [image: Wraith putting makeup on]
- When Sheppard joins the poker game - *Sympathy for the Devil* (The Rolling Stones)

  [image: black & white poker table]
- At the end of the episode - *Solitary Man* (Johnny Cash)

  [image: Bloody man lying on ground]

But there are a couple of other scenes with music but no lyrics that I'm not sure what songs they might be:

1. Very beginning of episode - western style acoustic guitar
2. As Wraith gets up and walks away after jumping off a building - heavy metal guitar strumming and getting progressively faster (short scene)

**What are the names/artists of 1. and 2., as well as other music used in the episode that I may have missed?**

Comment: If you have the episode, you could probably try identifying them with Shazam.

Comment: I can't use Shazam on my phone at the same time I'm streaming the show on my phone. I only have one device.

Comment: Some parts sounds like Drifter (Spaghetti western) theme.

Answer (score 3):

Checking from [*Stargate* wiki](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Vegas), 3 songs are played in the episode:

- Johnny Cash - *Solitary Man*
- Marilyn Manson - *The Beautiful People*
- The Rolling Stones - *Sympathy for the Devil*

Then if you check the [Johnny Cash entry in the wiki](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Johnny_Cash), it seems that *Personal Jesus* is played at some point (original song by Depeche Mode and covered by Johnny Cash).

Other music seem to be from Joel Goldsmith (composer of the *Stargate* OST), written especially for this episode. But I have no offical source, other than forums and Q&A websites.

Comment: Since I'm not too familiar with Marylin Manaon's music, I listened to The Beautiful People specifically for the music at B), and it wasn't part of the music after the wraith jumps. Same with Solitary Man at the very beginning of the episode with the buzzards flying.

Comment: @iMerchant I have edited my answer to remove the wrong parts and added that other music seem to be from Joel Goldsmith.

Comment: I think the wiki is wrong about Personal Jesus being in that episode after listening to the song. Certainly, none of the singing/lyrics were in the show. And I'm pretty sure none of the music made it either.

Comment: Would just like to highlight Solitary Man is a Neil Diamond song, which was covered by Johnny Cash!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who's interested in the music where the wraith stands up in the casino + the following chase...

The music is: Joel Goldsmith cover of Rage Against the Machine - Testify

Source: [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1252208/soundtrack?ref_=tt_trv_snd)